# Do Parallel Loops with MaxDegreesOfParallelism = 1 run on the calling thread?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach, parallel.for

The MSDN page does not really state what happens when `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreesOfParallelism` equals `1`.

I make extensive use of the  `Parallel` loops and I would like to debug it when it runs synchronously / single threaded.

I was wondering if I need to convert the `Parallel` loops to regular `for/each` loops manually or whether I can set the `MaxDegreesOfParallelism` to 1 to run it on the calling thread instead.

The order in my operations do not matter, I am aware that `Parallel` does not make any guarantees about the order of execution.

Comment: Parallel.ForEach always uses the calling thread, no matter the DOP. That's why it seems to block.  It's used for data parallelism, not asynchronous operations.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the Parallel Loops block, but the function bodies run on different threads depending on the Scheduler, don't they?

Comment: It seems to block only because the calling thread is used to process data along with the others. Threads don't run by themselves, they run on cores. When you want to process in-memory data using all 4/8/12 cores on your machine, nothing else will have a chance to run on them until the OS evicts the application threads. There's no reason to create yet another just to have it wait.

Comment: You should probably check [Walkthrough: Debugging a Parallel Application in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/walkthrough-debugging-a-parallel-application?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp). Visual Studio offers a lot of tools for parallel debugging. You won't find concurrency problems if you only use one thread

Comment: Why don't you just test debugging it and see if it works for you?

Answer (score 1):

The [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) method uses the current thread as one of the worker threads. By configuring the [`MaxDegreesOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) with the value `1`, most likely all the work will be carried out by the current thread alone, without involving the `ThreadPool` at all. Nevertheless this behavior is not explicitly specified in the official documentation. If you absolutely want this guarantee, you can either delve into the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs) and derive this guarantee by examining the implementation (and do it again each time a new .NET version is released), or switch to a simple `foreach` loop. The source code of the `Parallel` class is quite lengthy and convoluted, so if I was in your shoes I would pick the second option.